# AWS ec2 can't connect to flyvpn

Tags: amazon-ec2, vpn

My machine is CentOS 7, location is Singapore. I want to build a connection with flyvpn to crawl different LINE stickers on LINE store.

Now I can connect to flyvpn by setting cron, but the IP of EC2 hasn't changed, so the IP location is as same as before connected to flyvpn.

Anyone can help me to solve this problem, or another way to connect with VPN ?

Comment: Do you have flyvpn lock-in? Check the tinc and SoftEther VPN to get simpler configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with *flyvpn* but it sounds like you'll have to configure it to set **default route through the VPN** - there should be an option for that somewhere in the config.